# How to load a specific sprite and animation controller from my resources folder in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resources

Do you guys have any idea on how I can replace my current sprite with another? I tried to use Resources.Load() but it does not do anything else than blocking my animation.
I am currently doing it like this:

```
firebug.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load("Firebug Idle/Firebug Idle.png") as Sprite;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove Extension from file path

```
firebug.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load("Firebug Idle/Firebug Idle") as Sprite;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I have a question. Is this a thing from the newer versions, because every tutorial I saw had the extension?

Comment: Please check Unity API https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html